# corosync + pacemaker + percona agent in production

Tags: mysql, high-availability, database-administration, pacemaker, corosync

We are planning on implementing HA using pacemaker Corosync and Percona agent on mysql 5.7.1 with GTID. I googled for quiet a while and realized there isn't enough information. I was wondering if any one uses a similar stack for HA or if anyone could give any suggestions to common use case errors and suggestions regarding the whole thing.

It could be great if you could give an account of using pacemaker in production such as common issues , production problems , how much could you automate  etc ,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented Corosync/Pacemaker countless times in production environments. However, I have never used the "percona agent" you're referring too, so I can't speak directly to that.

Clusterlabs has great documentation on setting up Pacemaker clusters here:
   http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1-pcs/html-single/Clusters_from_Scratch/index.html

Their documentation will touch on the most common misconfigurations and best practices for HA clustering. My two cents: don't cut corners, use redundant everything, use fencing/stonith devices, and have an odd number of nodes when possible to keep quorum.

LINBIT also hosts plenty of technical guides that will help you setup a Pacemaker cluster, but all of them will use LINBIT's packages for installation, and DRBD for the replication piece (since that's their product):
    http://www.linbit.com/en/resources/technical-publications

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response. That's very helpful. I shall look at the links you have provided. anything else you would suggest for automation in prod ?

Comment: @nwarriorch: I think those references will get you pretty far. Come back and post another question once/if you have something more specific further along in your testing.